# Don't understand why I am getting Parse 206 error (UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("updatePositions", withParameters: ["username" : username, "location" : locationTitle, "instructor" : instructorSwitch.on, "guard" : guardSwitch.on, "sup" : supSwitch.on]) {
    (positions: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {

        self.currentUser.setValue(self.instructorSwitch.on, forKey: (self.shortTitle + "Instructor"))
        self.currentUser.setValue(self.guardSwitch.on, forKey: (self.shortTitle + "Guard"))
        self.currentUser.setValue(self.supSwitch.on, forKey: (self.shortTitle + "Sup"))

        self.currentUser.save(nil)

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    else {

        let errorAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Error", message: "There was an error while processing your request. This may be because the app could not connect to the internet. Please try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction (title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        errorAlert.addAction(actionCancel)

        self.presentViewController(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

When I run the above code, my goal to is to update the Parse Objects in my Data Browser and at the same time edit the same objects in `currentUser`.

As it stands now, the Login VC is shown if no one is logged in (based on a boolean value in Core Data). When a user logs in they are taken to the apps Home Page (and the boolean value is changed). If they were to shutdown the app and restart, they would be taken to the Home Page rather than the Login VC. I have a "dummy" VC where the Core Data entity is updated (I know it sounds redundant but it's there for a purpose that is unrelated to my issue).

**Login VC**

```
@IBOutlet var fullName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var helpButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var loginButton: UIButton!

var nameID: String!
var passwordStatus: Bool?
var username: String?
var userID: String?
var objectID: String!
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    checkInternetConnection()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func LoginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (fullName.text.isEmpty || password.text.isEmpty) {

        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Error"
        alert.message = "You have not completed the required fields!"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
        alert.show()
    }

    else {

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(fullName.text, password: password.text) {
            (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if (user != nil) {

                self.currentUser = user

                self.currentUser.save()

                //println(self.currentUser.objectForKey("username") as String!)

                if (self.currentUser.objectForKey("passwordChanged")  as Bool! == nil || self.currentUser.objectForKey("passwordChanged") as Bool! == false) {

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("password", sender: self)
                }

                else {

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("skipPassword", sender: self)
                }
            }

            else {

                let errorAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Error", message: "Profile not found. Please check your username and password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                let actionCancel = UIAlertAction (title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

                errorAlert.addAction(actionCancel)

                self.presentViewController(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "password") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as AccountSetup

        svc.username = fullName.text

    }

    else if (segue.identifier == "skipPassword") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as Agree

        svc.password = password.text
    }
}
```

---

The only place that there is a chance for the user to log out is in the app's Settings controller:

**Settings VC**

```
var choice: String!
var currentEmail: String!
var sendEmail: String!
var email: UITextField!
var listArray = NSArray (objects: "-", "-", "-", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")

var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

var res : NSManagedObject!
var context : NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentEmail = currentUser.objectForKey("email") as String!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 4
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    switch(section) {
        case 0: return 2
        case 1: return 9
        case 2: return 4
        case 3: return 1
        default: fatalError("Unknown number of sections")
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    choice = listArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString

    if (indexPath.row >= 3) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("positions", sender: self)

    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        var passwordAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Change Password", message: "For security reasons, you can not change your password through the app. We will send an email to " + currentEmail + ". If you rather us send it to another email, enter it below. Otherwise, click 'Send'.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let standardCancel = UIAlertAction (title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        let actionSubmit = UIAlertAction (title: "Send", style: .Default) { (action) in

            if (self.email.text.isEmpty) {

                self.sendEmail = self.currentEmail
            }

            else {

                self.sendEmail = self.email.text
            }

            PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(self.sendEmail){
                (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if (success == true) {

                    let emailAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Password", message: "An email containing information on how to change your password has been sent to " + self.sendEmail + ".", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    emailAlert.addAction(standardCancel)

                    self.presentViewController(emailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                else {

                    let errorAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Error", message: "There was an error while processing your request. This may be because the email is invalid or the app could not connect to the internet. Please try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    errorAlert.addAction(standardCancel)

                    self.presentViewController(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }

        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction (title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        passwordAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {

            (textField) in textField.placeholder = "Email"
            self.email = textField
        }

        passwordAlert.addAction(actionSubmit)
        passwordAlert.addAction(actionCancel)

        self.presentViewController(passwordAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


@IBAction func logoutPressed (sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()

    //code to change Core Data boolean value to start on Login is here but there is no need to put it (unrelated)

    tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

    performSegueWithIdentifier("goToLogin", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "positions") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as UpdatePositions;

        svc.locationTitle = choice
        println (choice)
    }
}
```

Like I've mentioned before, everything works up until the app is shutdown where the authentication is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up that there was an error in the 1.6.0 Parse SDK. Works fine with 1.6.5.